# Add missing dates to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have written a solution which basically adds missing date and sets the sales property for that date in my collection to 0 where it's missing like this:

```
int range = Convert.ToInt32(drange);
var groupedByDate = tr.Union(Enumerable.Range(1, Convert.ToInt32(range))
                       .Select(offset => new MyClassObject
                       { 
                           Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-(range)).AddDays(offset), 
                           Sales = 0 
                       })).GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                          .Select(item => new MyClassObject
                          { 
                              Sales = item.Sum(x => x.Sales), 
                              Date = item.Key 
                          })
                           .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                           .ToList();
```

The first solution where the dates from DB were grouped by and they were missing looked like this:

```
var groupedByDate = tr
                     .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Date)
                     .Select(item => new MyClassObject 
                     { 
                        Sales = item.Sum(x => x.QuantityPurchased), 
                        Date = item.Key.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") 
                     })
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Date)
                     .ToList();
```

I don't really like the way I did it in first solution, the code looks very messy and I honestly believe it can be written in a better manner..

Can someone help me out with this?

P.S. The first solution above that I've shown works just fine, but I would like to write something better which is more prettier to the eyes, and it looks quite messy (the first solution I wrote)...

Comment: To get a complete context, please explain tr and drange variables.

Comment: Could you select range of dates, then join on select (date, sum sales) ?

Comment: @Emanuele tr are the transactions from my database... And drange is the variable passed from a view , it basically represents a set of days for which I will show the transactions. Drange can be = 30,21,14 or 7

Comment: @BugFinder could you write an answer so that  I can see what you mean ?

Comment: This belongs on Code Review, not SO.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is there such a section in stackoverflow ? :D

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about generate the date range and then left join that with the result from your original query. And than set `Sales` to `0` when there is no match.

```
int range = 2;
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, range)
            .Select(offset => startDate.AddDays(-offset).Date);

var groupedByDate = from date in dates
                    join tmp in groupedByDate on date equals tmp.Date into g
                    from gr in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new MyClassObject
                    {
                        Sales = gr == null ? 0 : gr.Sales,
                        Date = date
                    };
```

Comment: @Magnus hey it says the follow: the type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin' ?

Comment: The date needs to be a DateTime and not a string. Drop the `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` from the original query.

Comment: @Magnus okay got it testing now :)

Comment: You should also remove the OrderBy and ToList from the original query.

Comment: @Magnus yes correct, thx. Btw,. Shouldn't the offset added offset => startDate.AddDays(offset).Date be in negative form ? Like this: offset => startDate.AddDays(-offset).Date  .... Because if the negative sign isn't there, the added offset would be in future( I was just testing and noticed this)...

Comment: If you want to go backwards from today's date then yes.

Comment: @Magnus thx a lot, btw. how can I now convert the datetime to be in this date format: yyyy-MM-dd  instead of converting it to string ?

Comment: You can do that in this query. Change your original query to use an anonymous type instead. `new { .Sales = ... }.` Than you can use MyClassObject in this query with date as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the easy way to do this:

```
var lookup = tr.ToLookup(x => x.TransactionDate.Date, x => x.QuantityPurchased);
var quantity = lookup[new DateTime(2017, 6, 29)].Sum();
```

If you want a range of dates then it's just this:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2017, 6, 1)
var query =
    from n in Enumerable.Range(0, 30)
    let TransactionDate = startDate.AddDays(n)
    select new
    {
        TransactionDate,
        QuantityPurchases = lookup[TransactionDate].Sum(),
    };
```

Simple.